# How can I make a process end when a different process ends?

Tags: automation, process

I'm on Windows 8.1.

Here's my situation: I play a game that requires a third-party software to record gameplay. I launch both at the same time through a BAT file:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\"
start lol.launcher.exe

cd "C:\Users\Craig\Dropbox\Programs\BaronReplays"
start BaronReplays.exe

exit
```

Is there anything I can use to set it up so that when one of these processes ends, the other ends along with it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a program killer. There are a number of them around, but provided you don't need a graceful shut-down [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) will do the job.

In the simplest case you should change your batch file to:-

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\Craig\Dropbox\Programs\BaronReplays"
start BaronReplays.exe

cd "C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\"
start /wait lol.launcher.exe

pskill BaronReplays.exe

exit
```

This will start the recorder, then the game, and when the game finishes stop the recorder, the key command being the `start /wait` which suspends the batch file until the started program ends.

If want either program to stop the other, then you need two batch files, each with a `start /wait` of one program, followed by a `pskill` of the other.

You need only launch one of the batch files, as it can start the other using:-

```
start cmd /c OtherBatch.cmd`
```

Finally, if you want a more elaborate solution, you could look at [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). Both these utilities are freeware.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help so far. The issue is that "lol.launcher.exe" actually is just the launcher, and the process that ends (and I want to trigger to end "BaronReplays.exe") is called "LolClient.exe". Any way to work around that?

Comment: `NirCmd WaitProcess` will do just that. You will need to put a short sleep after starting the launcher, to give the client time to start, unless the launcher terminates after starting the client, in which case you can use `start /wait` on the launcher.